# Using R to create a dataframe with random blocks of rows at a time

Tags: r, dataframe

I am at a complete loss.

I have five dataframes, each with five rows in them, let's say `df1, df2, ..., df5`.  These dataframes are fixed--there is no need to do any randomization within them.

I now want to create a dataframe with 500 rows in it, which is constructed by randomly appending each of the five dataframes 100 times, each with equal probability.  That is, the five rows of each dataframe are appended, *en bloc*, in random orders.

So, for example, one iteration could look like this:

```
ROW  df
1     df1[1,]
2     df1[2,]
3     df1[3,]
4     df1[4,]
5     df1[5,]
6     df5[1,]
7     df5[2,]
8     df5[3,]
9     df5[4,]
10    df5[5,]
...
496   df2[1,]
497   df2[2,]
498   df2[3,]
499   df2[4,]
500   df2[5,]
```

In other languages, I could draw a random number and use some sort of `case` terminology, but I can't seem to find a way to do this in R.

Can anyone help?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming I understand your question correctly, you could do something like this.

```
#we randomly sample the rows of each dataframe 100 times
rowSelection1<-sample(1:5, 100, replace=TRUE)
rowSelection2<-sample(1:5, 100, replace=TRUE)
rowSelection3<-sample(1:5, 100, replace=TRUE)
rowSelection4<-sample(1:5, 100, replace=TRUE)
rowSelection5<-sample(1:5, 100, replace=TRUE)


newDF<-rbind(df1[rowSelection1,], df2[rowSelection2,], df3[rowSelection3,], df4[rowSelection4,], df5[rowSelection5,]
```

I'm sure you could generalize it, but this is just a quick answer

This doesn't randomly sample from the dfs though, so you could do something like this

```
 createNewRows<-function(dfid){
     switch(dfid, 
            "1"=df1,
            "2"=df2,
            "3"=df3,
            "4"=df4,
            "5"=df5,)
 }

 rowList<-lapply(sample(1:5, 100, replace=TRUE), createNewRows)

 rbindlist(rowList)
```

Comment: This is close. I'm looking for the `df`s themselves to be randomized as blocks. This doesn't seem to quite give me that--it looks like it randomizes the rows themselves.

Comment: Actually, this is close.  I get an error when I try `unlist(rowList)`:  
Error in structure(res, levels = lv, names = nm, class = "factor") : 
  'names' attribute [5000] must be the same length as the vector [1000]

Comment: @user3251201 Ok so the edit now randomizes the dfs as blocks, so we take 100 samples instead of 500.  Not sure what is going on with the error.  It's working for me with a simple set of integer data frames.  You could maybe give a small sample of what your dataframes look like to test against

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand correctly.  You could try:

```
library(data.table)
df_list <- mget(ls(pattern="df\\d+"))  #using the data from @charles though without a set.seed()
res <- rbindlist(df_list[sample(seq_along(df_list),100, replace=TRUE)])

  res[1:10,]
 #        value
 #1: -0.81396114
 #2:  1.34798534
 #3:  0.08308022
 #4: -0.18476069
 #5:  0.58039641
 #6: -1.18188902
 #7: -0.74525519
 #8:  0.17258696
 #9: -1.20630019
#10:  1.42088692

  df_list[4:5]
 #$df4
 #      value
 #1 -1.1818890
 #2 -0.7452552
 #3  0.1725870
 #4 -1.2063002
 #5  1.4208869

 #$df5
 #       value
 #1 -0.81396114
 #2  1.34798534
 #3  0.08308022
 #4 -0.18476069
 #5  0.58039641
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the following can do what you want:

```
df1 <- data.frame(value = rnorm(5), group = "A")
df2 <- data.frame(value = rnorm(5), group = "B")
df3 <- data.frame(value = rnorm(5), group = "C")
df4 <- data.frame(value = rnorm(5), group = "D")
df5 <- data.frame(value = rnorm(5), group = "E")

df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)
require(data.table)
df <- rbindlist(rep(rbind(sample(df_list, 5)), 20))
```

`sample` randomly chooses the order of the next dataframe iteration, `rbindlist` is a fast rbind function from the data.table package, `rep` allows you to choose how many iterations (20 * 25 = 500 rows), `unlist` and `as.data.frame` get you the output you describe.

If you also want your rows within the df's permuted you can just add an additional `lapply` function.  Although it may not be the prettiest I believe it is relatively simple if you break it into the separate elements:

```
df <- rbindlist(rep(rbind(sample(lapply(df_list, FUN = function(x) as.data.frame(x[sample(1:5),])), 5)), 20))
```

Comment: This is close.  I'm looking for the `df`s themselves to be randomized as blocks.  This doesn't seem to quite give me that.

Comment: @user3251201 how does that differ from the first solution `df <- as.data.frame(unlist(rep(rbindlist(sample(df_list, 5)), 20)))`?  That randomizes the order of the dfs and binds them.  Or do both answers miss the mark, I'm not quite sure exactly what your request is.

Comment: So, I made some toy `df`s to play around with this:

`df1 <- data.frame(matrix(c(seq(1:5),rep("A",5)),nrow = 5, ncol = 2, byrow = FALSE))` (etc, just changing the letter in each `df`)

When I followed the first solution, it gave me the following output:

> head(df)
  unlist(rep(rbindlist(sample(df_list, 5)), 20))
1                                       1
2                                       2
3                                       3
4                                       4
5                                       5
6                                       1

Comment: Well, that didn't format nicely at all!  Essentially, it gives me a two-column `df` with the first column being a sequential 1-1000 list, and the second column being a random selection from within the columns of each of the original `df`s.  Somehow, I need to transfer both columns, _en bloc_.

Comment: @user3251201, even though you have selected the above answer, I have edited mine to work with multiple columns in the dataframes.  Feel free to use if you like.